# How to Force domain to with www

Tags: php, .htaccess

this is my `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shadyab.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.shadyab.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

but my site loaded with non `www`.

Comment: First of all, you should go inform yourself what the `L` flag does.

Comment: Your `non-www` to `www` rule block should be at the top of your htaccess before all other rules.

Comment: If you've got access to *httpd-vhosts.conf* it could be better to set up 2 `<VirtualHost>` directives to deal with it; one for the www sub-domain and one for the root which just redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Set condition to any address not starting with `www` and then redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Force www:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

## Force non-www:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```